# Show individual cluster elements in a dendrogram graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

It is easy to use two images to showcase what I am working to create. I have the following Python dendrogram, created from the following code (not currently reproducible, but wanted to show the code regardless):

```
# Initialize Plot
plt.figure(figsize=(18,9))

hierarchy.dendrogram(
    Z=Z,
    p=20,
    orientation="top",
    truncate_mode='lastp',
    leaf_rotation=45.,
    leaf_font_size=15.,
)

plt.show()
```

[image]

It is fairly simple and straightforward to this point. However, in an effort to better visualize the clusters, I'd like to show this same dendrogram, with string values for the elements in the cluster below the cluster, as such (created demo by pasting image into Excel and typing values):

[image]

Is this possible to do in Python with the dendrogram function, or in any other way? A hacky approach that uses subplots + a 2nd "graph" that is actually a table could be a possible solution, however it would be good if a less-hacky solution existed.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html leaf_label_func?

Comment: ooo yeah I will give it a look